# Linear Algebra - finding angle between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to this community and just started my first ever linear algebra course. Please could you help me? I need to understand why the angle between these 2 vectors is 120 degree?

w1 = $$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
w2 = $$1/2\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

Thank you so much.
Ped

Comment: One approach is to draw both vectors on the $xy$ plane, then either use an inverse sine or cosine or recognize the type of triangle formed to find the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle between $v$ and $w$ is $\cos^{-1} (\langle v , w \rangle )/ \|v\|\|w\|)$. In this case you get $\cos^{-1} (-\frac  1 2)$.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the notation just yet, could you tell me how you get to (-1/2)?

Comment: @PeddiePooh The inner product of $(a,b)'$ and $(c,d)'$ is defined as $ac+bd$. In this case we get $1(-\frac 1 2)+(0)\frac {\sqrt 3 } 2=-\frac 1 2 $.

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning linear algebra, here's a gem:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

Best linear algebra intro ever! Watch everything.

But anyway, you can associate that to a transformation from $\vec w_1 \to \vec w_2$.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7RM-ot2NWY&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=2 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=3.

Those explain how it works. Thus rotation becomes a mapping of where $\hat \imath, \hat \jmath$ go when defined by a matrix. One column for $\hat \imath, \hat \jmath$ each.

But in your case $\hat \imath=\vec w_1$ so I'll just approach it directly.

Both basis vectors are on a unit circle. So any point on that circle is defined by the co-ordinates $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) \qquad \text{Check the diagram.}$

[image]

So if $\hat \imath$ has been rotated, it has moved 120 degrees along that circle. Meaning it has migrated to $(\cos 120, \sin 120)$

[image: The unit circle in all its glory]

There! I could've jumped here immediately but since you're doing linear algebra I decided to be more helpful.